# Unity or OpenGL for a real time strategy game?

Tags: unity, opengl, c++, android

I'm trying to recreate an old game I use to play back in the day called Evony but I'm not sure what would be the best way to accomplish this **graphically**. It was originally written in **Flash** and I'm contemplating whether to do it using **Unity** or **openGL**. I'm not really sure how these types of games are made **graphically**, I looked at *Clash of Clans* but all it said is that they use "C++" so I'm lost. How would I go about making these types of games **graphically** using "C++" as most of these types of games are made for the android platform. I was thinking of using Unity but I'm afraid it would probably be too "bulky" and might make the game run slow, I want to be able to make it in C++ if possible so it can be more efficient. So again, how should I go about this?

[image: exampleGameGraphics1]

[image: exampleGameGraphics2]

Comment: Off-topic, read the [help].

Comment: https://unity3d.com/showcase/gallery

plenty of nice games made in unity.

Comment: will i be able to create a game like clash of clans using Unity? Will it be able to handle that many players? Also, does Unity provide a way to be able to communicate to a Java servlet server?

Comment: Clash of clans is effectively single player. The multi-player aspect is all server side. And if you're asking this question, a networked game is beyond your capabilities. Program something more manageable first.

Comment: If you're starting at zero, which based on your questions you absolutely are, use an Engine that has been tested, has a large userbase, and provides access to extensive tutorials. Unreal Engine and Unity are the options.

Comment: Since you're asking specifically about the performance of Unity, maybe you should check out their demo page: https://unity3d.com/unity/demos

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If you know C++ and already know OpenGL, you should use it. It can be way faster than Unity, but you do have to code **everything** from scratch

If you want a simpler solution that can still be very fast, use Unity. It has a big community that will help you out with your problems if you need help.

Comment: There is little reason to use C++ for performance, unless your application is *really* heavy.

Comment: C++ is not an engine, either. It's just a language. You could use a C++ engine that's buggy.

Comment: Note that answers for obviously-off-topic questions are not useful, and are often subject to more downvotes than the actual question.